Why are the gauge symmetries important?
So the rule is that if you change the field by multiplying it by a phase factor that varies you get a different equation, so to compensate for this you change the derivative operator to get rid of the derivative of the phase.
In that sense if you are allowed to change the derivative operator to get rid of anything you introduce by changing the field, then why that and not any other change you could possible devise?
Is there a proof or an argument to the effect that this is the only possible gauge that can be used and still have a physical theory? And why?

Multiplying by a phase factor (or in more technical language, a $U(1)$ gauge theory) is not the only gauge symmetry that is allowed or that is expressed in Nature. Gauge theories are important because they form the basis of the Standard Model. Wikipedia is a good starting point to read about all of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

@Andrew I know there are more, like SU(3), but my question is if we know about a possible limit to how many there can be?
In other words, are we just ruling out some by experiment? Or are there gauge theories that we prefer a priori for purely theoretical reasons?
In other words suppose you were Laplace demon and you could come up with all mathematically consistent gauge theories, would there be a way, other than experiment, to determine which ones are relevant?

This might help. For E/M, there are two common guages. But many more are possible. Gauge fixing

@LinaJane Nope, you eventually will need to do any experiment! As an example, $SU(5)$ is a possible gauge theory. In fact, not only is it mathematically possible, but it also can be used as the basis of a grand unified theory that unifies the gauge theories in the Standard Model. But we don't take $SU(5)$ super seriously as a candidate anymore, and why? Because we did experiments, and didn't find proton decay. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgi%E2%80%93Glashow_model#Proton_decay_in_SU(5)

Amazingly, there are some ways to rule out gauge group candidates for a gauge theory almost purely by algebraic considerations (experiment here enters by the fact that the gauge group of the standard model has to be embedded in it). See J. D. Hamilton's Mathematical Gauge Theory With Applications to the Standard Model of Particle Physics, chapter 9.5 for some discussion.

@LourencoEntrudo Very useful answer Lourenco

My (partial) understanding is that gauge theories are important because deep down they are connected with conservation laws. I recall that A. Zee described this connection in his popular book, Fearful Symmetry. The connection goes something more or less like this:
You postulate your own, new physical theory of the world. You reformulate it in terms of an explicit Lagrangian. Then you assert the invariance of the Lagrangian with respect to some symmetry transformation and see if a plausible set of conservation laws fall out when you turn the crank. If garbage falls out, then your theory is wrong and you go back and try something different.
Please let me know if I am remembering this correctly!
